# I have a method with two parameters in vue watch and one of them will not chnage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access a method out of my watch in with two parameters and here is my method

```js
onBoolianChange(value, willChange) {
            willChange = (value === false) ? true : false;
},


watch: {
        "edit_purchase.switch": function(val) {
            this.onBoolianChange (val, this.show_code)
            console.log(this.show_code)
        }, 
}
```

when I log `this.show_code` in my watcher it doesn't change

do you have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: You want `willChange` to be true if `value` is false? and are you sure that function inside watch is being called? have you `console.log(this.show_code)` anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

a `watch` is a eventListener which will only get triggered when the value ur `watch`ing gets changed somehow.

ur `edit_purchase.switch` needs to change to trigger ur function `onBooleanChange`
make sure ur `edit_purchase.switch` is changing its value

[Docs ref about watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)